# In aspdotnetstorefront, how can I add a different banner to each category without making different skins?

Tags: aspdotnetstorefront

My goal is to add different banners to the bottom of each category, right below the list of products.

This could be accomplished in the following ways, but I'm not sure how to do it in aspdotnetstorefront:

- Add custom CSS per category
- Add custom HTML per category

I'm trying to avoid adding content using Javascript, but will do as a last resort. That would be easy, but could cause maintenance issues.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet is to add the summary to the XMLPackage you are using for your category pages. Adding the following line will allow you to add the banners to the Summary field (editable via admin):

```
<xsl:value-of select="aspdnsf:GetMLValue($CurrentEntityNode/Summary)" />
```

This snippet assumes that the parameter CurrrentEntityNode has been declared:

```
<xsl:param name="CurrentEntityNode" select="/root/EntityHelpers/*[name()=/root/Runtime/EntityName]//Entity[EntityID = $CurrentEntityID]" />
```